# Reentrant lock not locking threads

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronization, race-condition, locks

I may have a problem understanding how threads work, which maybe the reason I am having this problem. The issue is that I have a REST API client and a Web client who both are confirming an order that was already placed (order belongs to a seller who will receive sale amount from each client).  Both clients access same code which writes to the database, lets call it Exclusive_Code_Block.

This Exclusive_Code_Block is in a method in a class, and I tried to put a lock on the Exclusive_Code_Block, like:

```
   try {
        confirmSerially.lock.lock();
        ***** code that accesses database is here ***********
       } finally {
        confirmSerially.lock.unlock();
       }
```

The lock is in a class (ConfirmSerially.java) in a component package:

```
package com.testing.component;

import java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantLock;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component

class ConfirmSerially {

     public ReentrantLock lock = new ReentrantLock(true);

     public ConfirmSerially () {
         
     } 
}
```

My confusion is definitely related to how threads work and how that relates to instance of class, in addition to poor java skill!

Both app client and Web client are entering the Exclusive_Code_Block. My expectation is that when REST app client gets to the lock section first, it will get the lock and go on to work inside the    Exclusive_Code_Block.  If Web client shows up it will not get the lock because app client has it.  Web client will get the lock when app client is done with the Exclusive_Code_Block, exits and releases the lock.

Not really sure how and where to place the lock so that each client/thread is forced to acquire the lock before going into the Exclusive_Code_Block. This is using Spring MVC with Hibernate.

Comment: Same ```ConfirmSerially ``` object?

Comment: Two different threads can simultaneously execute within your `code that accesses database` _\*IF\*_ they operate on different instances of your `ConfirmSerially` class. They should _not_ both be able to enter that same code block if they operate on the same instance. A `Lock` object does not prevent multiple threads from simultaneously executing the same block of code. It only prevents multiple threads from simultaneously locking the same `Lock`.

Comment: @SolomonSlow " A Lock object does not prevent multiple threads from simultaneously executing the same block of code..."  how can multiple threads simultaneously execute same block if there is only one lock, and only one of them has it?  This is where I think am lost here... how and where should I declare the lock so that only one thread at a time can get to it?

Comment: ..by ensuring that both threads try to obtain the lock before executing code that accesses the protected data.  It is up to you to structure your program flow to ensure that happens:)

Comment: @MartinJames In terms of putting the lock in a different class than the method that has  the protected code, am I doing it correctly?  Should the lock variable be static? How do I know if my REST client is or is not forking a new thread with a copy of the lock? Because if that is the case, then there are two instances of the lock and of course both threads will go into protected code at the same time... I don't know if that's the case.

Comment: @Dreary, And...? How many `Lock` objects are there in your program when it runs? I can guess from your code examples that there probably is only one `Lock` per `ConfirmSerially` object,\* but how many `ConfirmSerially` objects are there? \[\* If there's only meant to be one `Lock` per `ConfirmSerially` instance, then that fact would be more obvious if you made `lock` a `final` member, as in: `public final ReentrantLock lock = ...`]

Comment: I tried to eliminate the lock concept altogether and used synchronized keyword on the class level:

Comment: In short, I have 2 methods in 2 different classes in 2 different packages trying to access a protected code bock in a method in yet another class and package.
Method A (class A, package A): wants to call method C (with protected block) in class C package C
Method B (class B, package B): wants to call method C (with protected block) in class C package C

`
Method C in class C in package C has the synchronized keyword around the protected block:
`
synchronized (classC.class) {
   ***** protected code
}
`

Comment: Two threads going into synchronized block at same time is occurring only on cloud server, not on local machine, should that be a hint of some sort.

Comment: You still have not said whether or not the two threads that get in to the same critical section at the same time are locking the same `ReentrantLock` instance or different `ReentrantLock` instances. All your class/method/package A/B/C are beside the point. What matters is the identity of the lock objects. No two threads should ever be able to have the same `Lock` instance locked at the same time, regardless of what method locked it, but two or more threads absolutely _can_ enter the same "locked" code block at the same time if a different `Lock` instance is provided by each.

Comment: @SolomonSlow How can I know if they are locking the same lock or not? Code shown above.   What is needed is a way to serialize access to some common code placed in a method in some class.  But it is clear that every thread is getting its own copy of the lock, and also when I tried the synchronized keyword, still threads are ignoring it.  Now I am thinking of doing some database locking.

Answer (score 0):

I finally got it to work by making the lock static! With code I showed in the question, the lock was not `static`, so every thread got its own lock!! The suggestion to make the lock `final` I don't think that would work (I didn't actually try that, it didn't make sense as I think it has to be modified every time the lock is locked/unlocked.

My guess is that with multithreading, the lock has to be static, or else it just won't work, unless there is some roundabout way of doing that.